# How do I check if a Kubernetes pod was killed for OOM or DEADLINE EXCEEDED?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have some previously run pods that I think were killed by Kubernetes for OOM or DEADLINE EXCEEDED, what's the most reliable way to confirm that? Especially if the pods weren't recent.

Comment: I feel like this is an underrated question that still has no good answer. Imagine you're running 1000 pods of a service and some of them are OOMing. AFAICT, k8s still has no good way to answer the question "what OOM'd and when". Even the event log is less-than-helpful. Prove me wrong! :)

Comment: Related several years old issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81723

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the pods are still showing up when you type `kubectl get pods -a` then you get type the following `kubectl describe pod PODNAME` and look at the reason for termination. The output will look similar to the following (I have extracted parts of the output that are relevant to this discussion):

```
Containers:
  somename:
    Container ID: docker://5f0d9e4c8e0510189f5f209cb09de27b7b114032cc94db0130a9edca59560c11
    Image:      ubuntu:latest
    ...
    State:      Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
```

In the sample output you will, my pod's terminated reason is `Completed` but you will see other reasons such as `OOMKilled` and others over there.

Comment: In my situation I can't see the pods when using `kubectl get pods -a`. So what can I do about it? Maybe looking at kubelet's logs?

Comment: Look at the kubernetes events. It might also help

Comment: There is no -a option

Comment: Instead of `-a` I used `--all-namespaces`. Not sure if it's what he meant by it, but that's my best guess.

Comment: `-A` or `--all-namespaces` is the correct flag. Case is important.

Answer (score 8):

If the pod has already been deleted, you can also check kubernetes events and see what's going on:

```
$ kubectl get events

LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT    NAME                                               KIND                      SUBOBJECT                                     TYPE      REASON                SOURCE    MESSAGE
59m         59m          1        my-pod-7477dc76c5-p49k4                            Pod                       spec.containers{my-service}                   Normal    Killing               kubelet   Killing container with id docker://my-service:Need to kill Pod
```

Comment: this is nice but doesn't tell why it was killed

Comment: still gives nice details, at least I was able to get name of dead pod.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem where my pods were getting killed and deleted immediately. I was rolling the logs, but couldn't find much there. To see events, the pod had got deleted leaving no trace.

What i did was to put a watch on it, every 1 or 2s to catch the event on screen with command -

`watch -n2 "kubectl describe pod <pod_name>"`.

Not sure if this helps, but worked for me